# Why is Google login not running on my server?

Tags: php, google-signin

I have created a Google login. It is running perfectly on my localhost. However, when I pushed the code to my live server. It simply doesn't work. Here is what I did.

index.php

```
$google_client_id       = '***********.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$google_client_secret   = '******************';
$google_redirect_url    = '/url/profile.php';
$google_developer_key   = '';


$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName('Project name');
$gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
$gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
$gClient->setDeveloperKey($google_developer_key);

$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{ 
    $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($google_redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    return;
}

<body>
<?php
    if(isset($authUrl)) //user is not logged in, show login button
    {
         // html code
}?>
```

In profile.php

I have the same contents like index.php. It is getting redirected to this page from index.php. However, the page contents dont show up. It is because the gClient that I am declaring in profile.php is not getting declared. It is not authenticating the code which I am receiving from Google.

```
$google_client_id       = '***********.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$google_client_secret   = '******************';
$google_redirect_url    = '/url/profile.php';
$google_developer_key   = '';


$gClient = new Google_Client();
$gClient->setApplicationName('Project name');
$gClient->setClientId($google_client_id);
$gClient->setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$gClient->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
$gClient->setDeveloperKey($google_developer_key);

$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) 
{ 
    $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($google_redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    return;
}

<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a problem with this google_redirect_url, may it's not complete.
All the goolge developer credentials are already given on google developer console. link https://console.developers.google.com

At the end of the google_redirect_url,
there must have some code like.   abcd.php/oauth2callback';

Comment: It works on my local server.. apache. On live server; I dont understand whats happening.

Comment: I have created the variable for Oauth2Service(). You can see the code for that.

Comment: There must have some code regarding google access token.    if(isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{ 
 $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}


if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) 
{
 }

Comment: Or. . in my redirect url.. should I just put /url and not /url/profile.php ??

Comment: u should use full website path like this..                                            $google_redirect_url ='www.abcd.com/abcd/google_signup.php/oauth2callback';

Comment: I have used the same as my redirect url .. Its not getting it.